# Swipe Tab doesn't work, i don't see that on the screen

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, swipe

but come across a problem. When i run the app i don't see that my screen is swipes, and also i can't see tabs. Can you help
Here is my code:
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Toolbar toolbar;
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
            viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


            viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Home(),"Home");
           // viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Top(),"Top");
           // viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Buttom(),"Buttom");
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error on commented lines.
Here is my Pager Adapters code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Home fragments, String titles){

        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);


    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

In my XML i've only Viewpager, Toolbarand TabLayout.
Please Help.

Comment: can you add na image of problem, I dont see any error with your code but with na image I can help better.

Comment: Please look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Probably** is this:

```
Home fragments
```

Try **change** to this:

```
Fragment fragments
```

**Method** be like this:

```
public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles){

        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);


    }
```

So you in the `method` you have `Home fragments` as `paramter` and when you call other fragments diferent than Home because `parameter` is Home you get error, to fix just do like I said change **parameter** to `Fragment fragments`. it's a small mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your type of parameter in `addFragments`

try this :

```
public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles)
```

instead of

```
public void addFragments(Home fragments, String titles)
```

I hope this may help you

Comment: mmmh ok, i'm looking for something else

Comment: i edtied my post

Comment: You now now it works but still i can't see my toolbar tabs

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your xml layout file.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In your mainactivity

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout_ordering.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout_ordering.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout_ordering));


    tabLayout_ordering.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Then create a class for your pager adapter.

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
            return fragmentFoods;
        case 1:
            FragmentDrinks fragmentA = new FragmentA();
            return fragmentA;

        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
}
```